# How to change login test scenario to function

Tags: javascript, function, cypress

I have the following login scenario for my application using Cypress.io.  Currently I am having to use all of the scenario below before each of my tests.  Is there a way to turn this into a function that I can then call as use as a 'beforeEach' test scenario?

```
describe('My Login Test', function (){
    it('Visit Risk App Landing Page', function (){
        const typedText = 'email@address.com'
        cy.visit('https://bvt-riskassessment.lmkcloud.net')
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.get('a.auth0-lock-alternative-link').contains('Not your account?').click()
        cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').first()
        .type(typedText)
        .should('have.value', typedText)
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.url().should('eq','https://bvt-riskassessment.lmkcloud.net/workflow')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out cypress commands. You can create custom commands and do a login command that is called in before each that has all your login steps.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Parent-Commands

Ie Cy.login

Answer (score 1):

In **support/commands.js**:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
    .visit('/login')
    .get('#email_input').type(email)
    .get('#password_input').type(password)
    .get('button.submit').click()
});
```

Then in your **test spec**, you can reference:
`cy.login('foo@bar.com', 'pass123')`

**Documentation:**